# SOAP extension is not loaded

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, soap-api-v2

I have a eCommerce portal https://ninobambino.in/,and I want to connect it a erp system.
When I browse https://ninobambino.in/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/wsdl/1/, I am getting valid XML data.
but When browsing https://ninobambino.in/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/ gives me “0 SOAP extension is not loaded”.
 I am using magento 1.9 .
Please help me.

Comment: you need to enable sop from php.ini file

Comment: how to enable to soap in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

This is an **environment** question more than a Magento one

Depending by your environment the way to install / enable SOAP php extension can be very different... check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=php+enable+soap or make your own search, providing more info about your environment

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Php.ini** File from phpmyadmin open in text editor and search for **;extension=php_soap.dll** and just remove ; symbol and after that restart your Wamp/xamp services and then **refresh** your url page..enjoy